# Should I prefer addition or logical OR operator if both would give the same result?

Tags: c++, operators, logic, addition, or-operator

Should I prefer `+` (addition) operator or `|` (or) operator if both would give the same result?

I understand that addition and logical OR are different things. But they sometimes do the same thing in some macros, especially when playing with bytes and bits. Which one should I prefer in this case?

Example:

```
uint8_t Byte1 = 0x02;   // 0000 0010
uint8_t Byte2 = 0x80;   // 1000 0000
uint16_t Word1, Word2;  // 0000 0010 1000 0000 = 640 = 0x0280

Word1 = (Byte1 << 8) + Byte2;
Word2 = (Byte1 << 8) | Byte2;

std::cout << "Word1 = " << Word1 << std::endl;
std::cout << "Word2 = " << Word2 << std::endl;
```

Output:

> Word1 = 640
>   Word2 = 640

Comment: This one's tricky because neither is a clear winner in terms of readability.

Comment: What you should prefer for what? Performance? Well, bit operations are slightly faster but I don't think you'll ever notice that. Readability? I think they're both clear but it depends on their _meaning_.

Comment: @Adriano The only place where I've seen this matter is with SSE where logical instructions have 3 IPC throughput vs. only 2 IPC for addition. (on current Intel processors)

Comment: @Mysticial I agree, I did mean it's pretty useless in 99.9% of cases to care about this stuff (for performance).

Comment: @Adriano I recently did a small study to see if "complicated" instructions consume more power than "simple" instructions. (To make an argument that `|` is better since it uses less power.) But in the end, it turns out that the rest of the processor logic overwhelms everything that even floating-point additions and multiplications turned out to have the same (per-instruction) power consumption. lol... so much for that... :)

Comment: @Mysticial I didn't even think about power consumption!!! I have some colleagues whom went crazy for that. I'm happy these details are pretty meaningless now days...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When manipulating bit patterns, logical operators are appropriate. When manipulating numeric values, arithmetic operators are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid mixing bit operations and arithmetic operations in the same expression, so I would write

```
Word1 = (Byte1 * 256) + Byte2;
```

but

```
Word2 = (Byte1 << 8) | Byte2;
```

Readability is the only thing to worry about here, because a good optimizer should produce the same exact code for both expressions.

Comment: Note that with signed types, division by powers of two is not equivalent to right-shifting.  For values that happen to be positive, the behaviors will be equivalent but shifting will often be faster, sometimes considerably so.  For negative values, right-shifting is implementation-defined, but in most implementations `(x>>2)` is defined usefully, and provides a faster and clearer alternative to any equivalent expression using the `/` operator.